# Laravel PHPUnit returning 404

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, testcase, laravel-7

For laravel API I have write the test cases. But whenever I am running the test cases it always failed with below error,

```
1) Tests\Feature\CompanyTest::orgTest
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.
```

After adding the `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` to testcase code it return the below error,

```
1) Tests\Feature\CompanyTest::orgTest
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: POST domainname/index.php/api/company

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithExceptionHandling.php:126
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:415
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:113
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:507
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:473
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:332
/tests/Feature/CompanyTest.php:21
```

> My Code in Test File is,

```
public function orgTest()
    {
        $requestData = ["organizationId" => 10,"offset"=>1,"limit"=>10,"notificationId"=>""];
        $response = $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response->postJson('/index.php/api/company',$requestData);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

I have googled the error and tried many solutions but unable to succeed. Anyone please let me know whats the issue.

Comment: post to `/api/company` the HTTP tests will lookup the route and call it directly.

Comment: @apokryfos tried but no success

Comment: Can you show use your route declaration in `routes/api.php`?

Comment: @gbalduzzi my route in routes/api.php is `Route::any('company','CompanyController@companyindex');`

Answer (score 2):

It is a 404 error, so your webpage is not found :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: POST domainname/index.php/api/company
```

Bad way to go, post to `/api/company` or with `/index.php/api/company` but not with "domainname" !

If it is not working, check your route config for that api route. Are your controller and action declared well ?

Comment: I have tried with `/index.php/api/company` only. Also, I am able to access this API from the postman

Comment: Which url are you putting inside postman ? Do you make some checks inside your action code and allow only some HTTP methods ie  GET rejected, POST ok ?

Comment: I am putting the same URL with domain name in postman and its working correctly. Also, I have tried to get, and post issue is the same.

Comment: hmm strange... if I were you I will check the action code and the route config very closely to check twice everything is well formatted. 
and I will do some tests with `/api/company`.

Comment: Did you follow some tutorial like these one : 
https://medium.com/@mscherrenberg/unit-testing-your-api-in-laravel-5-6-7172bcdc593d

Comment: Maybe these one looks better : https://www.twilio.com/blog/unit-testing-laravel-api-phpunit

Comment: I am tried the same but no success. The only difference is I am not using migration.

Answer (score 1):

By default, laravel's routing does not explicitly show that it is a php file rather than it has dedicated endpoints which you decide on the routing file. So index.php shouldn't be a valid route for laravel.

A [404 error](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) status code refers to a Not Found Error. Maybe the api url that you are trying to access does not match the one inside the routes file whether you are using web.php or api.php.

I suggest using `php artisan route:list` on the base path of the project to properly see that the route you wanted is registered and match it from there.

Comment: I have check with route list and its same URL which I am trying to access

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that PHPUnit can't find not only this URL but the whole website. You could check it by request to "/" in your test.

If I'm right, first of all, I'll suggest checking the param `APP_URL` in your `.env.testing`. Usually, I set it as `APP_URL=http://localhost`, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 code means there was nothing found at the specified route. It could be the route you specified `index.php/api/company`. Try routing to `[host:port]/api/company`